# Python, Pandas replacing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV data set which looks something like this:

```
Fruit
1
2

4
0
2

2
1
```

I am trying to create a new column by using a data frame (`adjusted_data`).

```
adjusted_data["Fruit"].replace("", -1, inplace=True)
adjusted_data["Fruit"] = adjusted_data["Fruit"]/100
adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Fruit"]>0,"Some",adjusted_data["Fruit"])
adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Fruit"]==-1,"Unknown",adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"])
adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Fruit"]==0,"None",adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"])
```

I am expecting my dataset to look like this:

```
Fruit    Daily Fruit Intake 
0.01     Some
0.02     Some
-0.01    Unknown
0.04     Some
0.0      None
0.02     Some
-0.01    Unknown
0.02     Some
0.01     Some
```

However, when I groupby it appears all of the "Unknowns" are actually nan. I don't understand this as I replace empty cells with -1. I guess the replace function is not working as expected. I have tried lots of different things, but with n luck. All help is appreciated.

Kind regards,

C

Comment: Can you post what exactly your groupby function is?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line

```
adjusted_data["Fruit"] = adjusted_data["Fruit"]/100
```

After you scale your data by 100, all of your `unknown`s are now `-0.01`, all of your `none`s are still `0`, and all of your `some`s are still `>0`.

So the following logical vector is all falses (the entries that were `-1` are now `-0.01`

```
adjusted_data["Fruit"]==-1
```

instead, if you change your where statement to either

```
adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Fruit"]==-0.01,"Unknown",adjusted_data["Fruit"])
```

or

```
adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Fruit"]<0,"Unknown",adjusted_data["Fruit"])
```

you should get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks David. You are correct that is an error, but I think that was just an error that I made after several attempts of fixing it and I forgot to scale down by 100. I am still getting issues with this. When I use df.to_csv and look at the actual data, the missing elements are being recorded as "". When I try to count the number of element == "", I get 0. So in the above example the problem is with the line adjusted_data["Fruit"].replace("", -1, inplace=True) as it can't find any data with "", despite it definitely being there. I am unsure as to why this is happening :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the new column via:

```
    adjusted_data["Fruit"] = adjusted_data["Fruit"]/100
    adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Fruit"]==-1,"Unknown",adjusted_data["Fruit"])
    adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(adjusted_data["Fruit"]==0,"None",adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"])
    adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"] = np.where(np.logical_or(adjusted_data["Fruit"]==0,adjusted_data["Fruit"]==-1),adjusted_data["Daily Fruit Intake"],"Some")
```

Not sure why the first wouldn't work still :(

Comment: I am glad that you found solution...but idk why my solution doesn't worked on your side

Comment: Same! For some reason it didn't want to compare -1 < 0.